# Selection of value error

Tags: javascript, selection

I am trying to determine what the total is equal to and then do a job pertaining to each selection. My first selection is if the total is 2, 3, or 12, then you lose. If it is a 7 or a 11, you lose. Anything else the point is established. First my code looked like this, but every single time, it went to else. The total is being calculated through 2 random numbers added together using this function:

```
   Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
```

```
function game()
 {
if(total==2 || total==3 || total==12)
    {
        alert("You lose. Please start a New Round");
    }
if(total==7 || total==11)
    {
        var temp= 2 * bet;
        alert("You win $" + temp);
    }   
else 
    {
        alert("Point Established. Roll again.");
        var point=total;
        setTimeout(rolldice2,3000);
    }
 }
```

Then I changed it to this:

```
 function game()

 {
if(total==2 , 3 , 12)
    {
        alert("You lose. Please start a New Round");
        return;
    }
if(total==7 , 11)
    {
        var temp= 2 * bet;
        alert("You win $" + temp);
        return;
    }   
else 
    {
        alert("Point Established. Roll again.");
        var point=total;
        setTimeout(rolldice2,3000);
    }
 }
```

But it just says you lose no matter what. Then I finally took out return. It does the first 2 and not else. I want to be able to choose one- depending on what the variable total is equal to- and then perform its jobs and then leave the function.

Comment: Where are you calculating the total at?

Comment: As much as I appreciate craps, the code you have provided does not divulge enough information for us to help

Comment: the total is being calculated before. I did not include it as it is being calculated fine. I know this because it displays the total and then does the above function. That is where the problem occurs. The total is calculated by adding two random numbers(dice together) Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);

Comment: @JamesWhitney Would you like me to include the entire Javascript file?

Comment: If you can show us what your `var total = ...` line looks like, that would help. You could also toss an alert at the top of the `game()` function that displays the value so that you are CERTAIN of what is going in there. I would also refactor your method similar to @sdespont 's solution as case statements are a little cleaner.

Comment: Quick idea for you! is `total` a global variable? Are you re-calculating that every time a roll is made?

Comment: It's probably going to be simplest at this point to just include your entire JS file, yeah. As it is, you're not understanding what the others mean by "show us `total`" - there's going to be a massive downvote tide and if you don't fix your question I suspect it will wind up being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `total` variable is `undefined`

Pass `total` to your function and do a `switch` statement

```
 function game(total)
 {
    switch(total)
    {
        case 2 : 
        case 3 :
        case 12 : {
                    alert("You lose. Please start a New Round");
                    return;
                  }
        case 7 : 
        case 11 :
                 {
                    var temp= 2 * bet;
                    alert("You win $" + temp);
                    return;
                 }   
        default : 
                {
                    alert("Point Established. Roll again.");
                    var point=total;
                    setTimeout(rolldice2,3000);
                }
    }
 }
```

Comment: That's a better structure that is more easily read than the code that the OP provided, however it does not fundamentally change how the code gets processed, and would most likely provide the same result.

Comment: I don't agree, In OP code, total is undefined. In my example, total is pass to the function and is processed.

Comment: Where he said "But it just says you lose no matter what." indicates that it is always entering the 2, 3, 12 case every time. That would imply that there is missing code to get the total that the OP didn't share with us.

Comment: You solution does help with the fact that OP forgot to have 7 & 11 be `else if` and just `if`, which would also not work correctly.

Comment: total is not undefined. It is defined in a previous function.

Comment: @krillgar I added else if and that did not work. As I added to my OP and to other coments, the variable total is defined in a previous function.

Comment: I feel foolish. As you all mentioned. Total was undefined. All I did was write var total= total; and it worked. Thanks for pointing this out to me and take me out of denial. Thanks again.